# PHP CURL issue | Header Context Type is not sending

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to consume an API through PHP Curl but the appropriate headers are not being sent.

This is my code:

```
$array = array("user"=>"user", "password"=>"password");
$payload = http_build_query($array);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://...");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload)
    )
); 

// But, the response is:

/* 
["content_type"]=>
  string(23) "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(400)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(288) 
*/
```

Could someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: In the API specifications, what do you have regarding the headers?

Answer (score 0):

The `content-type` in the response refers to the `content-type` returned by the API you are querying. 
From the response you put, it seems like the API is experiencing errors based on the parameters you supplied since the response code is **400**. This most likely means you are not passing the correct parameters, not passing an `authorization` header (where required), or not sending the correct content type the API requires.